# Spring boot REST API handle authorization code GRANT_TYPE

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-social

I have a application consist:

- Web app.
- Oauth2 server.
- Resource server.

Normally, web app send request to `Oauth2 server` to get `access_token` then use it to call api from `Resource server`. This is `grant_type: password` flow.

As `grant_type: authorization_code`, web app send redirect to `SSO server`. If login successfuly, SSO server will redirect to web app with code. Web app will use this code to get access_token from `SSO server`. In here, i think SSO server and Oauth2 server is one and i config like that.

My issue is i want to custom UI of SSO `formLogin()`, using angular. So, i create second web app to do it. I think this web app can fetch authorization code from `SSO server` then check and redirect this code to primary web app then use code to fetch `access_token` like `grant_type: password`.

1. Is these possiable?
2. If `SSO server` additional `social login` like `Google, Facebook...`. My `SSO server` can do that?

Maybe my question is not exactly. So, give me your idea or please show to me what i wrong. Thanks all.

Comment: Check this authO has complete tutorial on it https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-angular-user-authentication/

Comment: @brijesh auth0 is third party authenticaion? I just want build my SSO server for individual purpose